Ubuntu crashes every night while I am away from the keyboard due to a segmentation violation
This is a desktop computer at my workplace which I have admin access to. I never encounter any issues while using it, but it crashes sometime after I go home for the night. Every time I return to the desktop, I encounter a message saying that Ubuntu ran into an issue and it needs to be logged out of. I haven't been able to click on "Show Details" because the dialogue box with that option is frozen. The only thing I can do is click "Log Out" on a separate dialogue box that is open. After logging back in, everything looks and works fine.
Since this happens overnight, I haven't been able to narrow down what type of processes may be leading to this crash. Side note, I am relatively new to Linux and Ubuntu, so I apologize if I am not being very precise about the information I am providing.
I found some crash files. They are /var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-shell.100x.crash. They are very large files, ~50 MB. I don't know how to interpret them, so I put two of them up on pastebin (_usr_bin_gnome-shell.1001.crash and _usr_bin_gnome-shell.1002.crash), but I didn't include the large chunk at the end under CoreDump: base64 since that part took up about 45MB.
The best I can make of the crash files is that there was a segmentation violation (see near the bottom of the excerpt I included at the bottom), but I don't know how to determine what program caused it.
My question is this: where should I look next to narrow down what program is causing the crash? Let me know what else I can do to provide information that will be helpful to get to the bottom of this. Thanks.

Here is a further abridged version of the crash files I linked on pastebin:
ProblemType: Crash
Architecture: amd64
CurrentDesktop: ubuntu:GNOME
Date: Tue Oct 22 11:14:06 2024
Dependencies:
 <1000 lines containing packages installed on my system>
DistroRelease: Ubuntu 24.04
ExecutablePath: /usr/bin/gnome-shell
ExecutableTimestamp: 1723792607
Package: gnome-shell 46.0-0ubuntu6~24.04.4
PackageArchitecture: amd64
ProcCmdline: /usr/bin/gnome-shell
ProcCwd: /home/hemondla
ProcEnviron:
 LANG=en_US.UTF-8
 PATH=(custom, no user)
 SHELL=/bin/bash
 XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=<set>
ProcMaps:
 <a few thousand lines omitted>
ProcStatus:
 Name:  gnome-shell
 Umask: 0002
 State: S (sleeping)
 Tgid:  697325
 Ngid:  0
 Pid:   697325
 PPid:  696845
 TracerPid: 0
 Uid:   1002    1002    1002    1002
 Gid:   1002    1002    1002    1002
 FDSize:    64
 Groups:    4 24 27 30 46 100 122 136 1002 
 NStgid:    697325
 NSpid: 697325
 NSpgid:    697325
 NSsid: 697325
 Kthread:   0
 VmPeak:     5163076 kB
 VmSize:     5117216 kB
 VmLck:        0 kB
 VmPin:        0 kB
 VmHWM:   430536 kB
 VmRSS:   102764 kB
 RssAnon:      76184 kB
 RssFile:      26580 kB
 RssShmem:         0 kB
 VmData:      462228 kB
 VmStk:      132 kB
 VmExe:        8 kB
 VmLib:   241204 kB
 VmPTE:     1756 kB
 VmSwap:      144896 kB
 HugetlbPages:         0 kB
 CoreDumping:   1
 THP_enabled:   1
 untag_mask:    0xffffffffffffffff
 Threads:   27
 SigQ:  0/253463
 SigPnd:    0000000000000000
 ShdPnd:    0000000000000000
 SigBlk:    0000000000000000
 SigIgn:    0000000001001000
 SigCgt:    0000000100004008
 CapInh:    0000000000000000
 CapPrm:    0000000000000000
 CapEff:    0000000000000000
 CapBnd:    000001ffffffffff
 CapAmb:    0000000000000000
 NoNewPrivs:    0
 Seccomp:   0
 Seccomp_filters:   0
 Speculation_Store_Bypass:  thread vulnerable
 SpeculationIndirectBranch: conditional enabled
 Cpus_allowed:  fff
 Cpus_allowed_list: 0-11
 Mems_allowed:  00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000000,00000001
 Mems_allowed_list: 0
 voluntary_ctxt_switches:   1664978
 nonvoluntary_ctxt_switches:    7269
 x86_Thread_features:   
 x86_Thread_features_locked:
Signal: 11
SignalName: SIGSEGV
SourcePackage: gnome-shell
Uname: Linux 6.8.0-45-generic x86_64
UserGroups: adm cdrom dip lpadmin plugdev sambashare sudo users
_HooksRun: no
CoreDump: base64


Here are my system specs:
Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              ASUS PRIME X670-P
Memory:                                      64.0 GiB
Processor:                                   AMD Ryzen™ 5 7600X × 12
Graphics:                                    AMD Radeon™ Graphics
Graphics 1:                                  NVIDIA GeForce RTX™ 3060
Disk Capacity:                               4.0 TB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            0823
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            X11
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-45-generic


If you logout of Gnome at the end of the workday, does the system still crash overnight?

Please run "top" when this pc is iddle (in the same state as it is when you leave it for the night) and post the first few lines of the output. You can do this a few times (the output changes because it says which processes are running in real time) but try not to post duplicate lines.
